# Does this study show vaccines are more likely to result in COVID-19 Omicron infection?

Tags: covid-19, vaccines

A popular [tweet](https://twitter.com/ezralevant/status/1474106318206255113) claims:

> Holy moly.
>
> This study shows that after three months the vaccine effectiveness of Pfizer & Moderna against Omicron is actually negative. Pfizer customers are 76.5% more likely and Moderna customers are 39.3% more likely to be infected than unvaxxed people.
>
> https://medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.12.20.21267966v2.full.pdf+html
>
> [image]

Does this study show that Pfizer and Moderna vaccines are 77% and 39% more likely to result in COVID-19 Omicron infection, three months after inoculation?

Comment: @JBentley, yes thanks.